# Is there a taxonomy of species with emergence and extinction dates?

Tags: taxonomy, database

I know the NCBI has a list of each species and their place in the evolutionary tree. But do they have the **dates** that these species existed? Does any such database (partial or complete) exist anywhere?

For example, [Adelobasileus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adelobasileus) on Wikipedia says "about 225mya", so that would be one example date. Obviously they aren't super exact, but it would be cool if this has already been collected somewhere.

Comment: for the vast majority of species those will just be question marks.